# Change distance/dash/gap values in Highmaps for dashStyle

Tags: highcharts, multiline

Pretty cool that one can use [different dash types](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-dashstyle-all/) for the maps. However, the values for the gaps are somewhat problematic, as, in my case, they are much to wide:

[image]

The red line in the left part is the country border for Sudan/South Sudan. There should be much more dashes and gaps then the 5, on a border which is thousands of kilometres long.

Or this on for West Bank (which is not yet optimised - there is a polygon and a polyline layer, both simplified with the same value, but with different results): there is even no gap visible:

[image]

Is there anyway to change a parameter somewhere in order to produce more dashes and gaps on a given distance?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/3u61xctj/7/) and the code

```
    {
        type: 'mapline',
        data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['BNDL25_04_boundaries_3'], 'mapline'),
        color: '#f00',
        dashStyle: 'ShortDash'
    },
```

Comment: Hi @luftikus143, You can the 'dashStyle' property as a string with numbers (more info: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dasharray/), but the lowest value seems to be 1. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n94Lfwjp/

Comment: @ppotaczek: Thanks for that. But that doesn't work for DashDot styles, no? As far as I understand, it only indicates the length in »line« and »gap«. But that won't generate dots, as far as I tried. Any hints?

Comment: Even for `dashStyle: 'dot'` there are no dots: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7obp6gk8/ It is probably related with the map scale and zoom.